# 'win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (87, 'UpdateResource', 'The parameter is incorrect')' error when assigning icon with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, executable, ico

I am using **pyinstaller** to create an executable from a **.py** file type and attaching an icon to it using the command

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon="test.ico" test.py
```

The **'.ico'** is *500px by 500px* and *24bit depth* and was created with **Photoshop** and exported as a **'.bmp'** and then manually changed to a **'.ico'** and worked fine when assigned to a folder but when trying to assign it to the **pyinstaller executable** I keep getting the error:

```
raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (87, 'UpdateResource', 'The parameter is incorrect')
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it appears that the icon file was not generated correctly.
If anyone is having this issue use: [icoconverter.com](https://www.icoconverter.com/) to convert your image properly